# How to improve my iteration over an object of objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save every 'percentage' value from a .json into an array:

[image]

This code is working right now:

```
let percentage = []
for(var key in res['data']){
    percentage.push(res['data'][key].percentage);
}
```

But I feel like I can improve it to only use one line. I tried mapping the values to a variable, as I did in the past like this:

```
let percentage = res['data'].map(res => res.percentage);
```

But instead I'm getting a 'TypeError: res.data.map is not a function' error. How can improve my code to map it in just one line like this?:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is an *object*, not an array, so you can't call `map` on it. But, you could use `Object.values` instead:

```js
const res = {
  data: {
    0: {
      percentage: 8.1
    },
    1: {
      percentage: 47
    },
    2: {
      percentage: 87
    }
  }
};
const percentage = Object.values(res.data).map(({ percentage }) => percentage);
console.log(percentage);
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for and worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

map function you can use with Array. Since you input is an object, use Object.values.
`Object.values(res.data).map(({ percentage }) => percentage);`

Answer (score 2):

One short and easy way is to use lodash library (use npm to get it)

Therein, you will have a _.map method which you can use straightaway, like this

```
_.map(res.data, (obj) => obj.percentage)
```

Another way which many people here are suggesting are and why you should use it is:

1- The first thing here is the use of for..in also iterates over the object's prototype chain properties as well.
Here on mozilla page :

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

So, you should be using Object.values to get only its own enumerables.

2- Once you have the values as list, you can run a map function on it. 
Here, in the arrow function passed to map, do object destructuring {propertyName} (ES6 specific) to extract the property to the propertyName variable.

So , the code will become :

```
Object.values(res.data)
.map( ({percentage}) => percentage)
```

I hope this clears it all.
EOD.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is not an array and you can not implement `map()` on object other than array.  You have to use `Object.values()` to implement `map()`:

```
let percentage = Object.values(res.data).map(res => res.percentage);
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can do Object.values and then use map on that

```js
let resp = {

  "data": {
    "0": {
      "percentage": 8.1
    },
    "1": {
      "percentage": 9.1
    },
    "2": {
      "percentage": 10.1
    }
  }
}

let perc = Object.values(resp.data).map(function(item) {
  return item.percentage;
})
console.log(perc)
```

Answer (score 0):

`res.data` is an object, not an array, so no `map` method is available at this point.

Since your `data` object has numerical keys, you can easily transform it into an array with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), then map it. You can also shorten the mapping function a bit by using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
let percentage = Object.assign([], res.data).map(({percentage}) => percentage);
```